# What groupware/collaboration system to choose?

Tags: php, utf-8, collaboration, mindmapping

I am looking for a good (stable enough, intuitive enough, and the more technologically modern and advanced - the better) **free PHP-based** online *groupware/collaboration* system. **100% UTF-8** is a requirement. OOP-style code is an advantage. And collaborative mindmapping would be a cool feature to have. The team is of ~20 people. Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't programming related. You can't make a question programming related just by mentioning that you want something written in a particular language and making the language bold.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Horde](http://www.horde.org/groupware/). I've only tangentially been involved with it, but it seems to meet all of your requirements.